# Highcharts : how to set yAxis max value inside angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

i'm trying to get yaxis max values..

javascript : chart.yAxis[0].max;

when i try in angularjs as it has slightly different properties :

Highcharts.charts[0].yAxis[0].max gives undefined, 
Highcharts.charts[0].yAxis[0].getExtremes.max gives undefined.

is there any way to get the max value inside angularjs controller?

Comment: can you share your specific chart data that you want to display. or a quick fiddle !

Answer (score 0):

getExtremes is function, not object. You have to call it to obtain extremes.

```
 var max = chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes().max;
```

Docs: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis.html#getExtremes